# Google test - Comparing an array as a void* parameter

Tags: c++, googletest, void-pointers

I got the following test to do what I want it to.

```
MOCK_METHOD2(write, void(unsigned char*, int));


unsigned char bar[] = {1,2,3};

EXPECT_CALL(foo, write(_, sizeof(bar))).With((ElementsAreArray(bar)));
```

But if I change the parameter type to void* for the function as below it will not compile.

```
MOCK_METHOD2(write, void(void*, int));
```

With error:

```
error C2182: 'abstract declarator' : illegal use of type 'void'
    gmock-matchers.h(2536) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcherImpl<Container>' being compiled
    with
    [
        Container=const std::tuple<void *,unsigned char>
    ]
```

This makes sense I guess, but I cannot find a way to solve this where the argument is a void*, which it should be here. Is there any possibility to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`ElementsAreArray` needs to dereference the argument pointer to compare it, and the `void*` pointers cannot be dereferenced. You will need to wrap `memcmp` into a custom matcher to compare buffers passed as `void*`:

```
MATCHER_P2(HasBytes, bytes, size, "") {
  return arg1 == size && memcmp(arg0, bytes, size) == 0;
}

EXPECT_CALL(foo, write(_, sizeof(bar))).With(Args<0, 1>(HasBytes(bar, sizeof bar)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using `ElementsAreArray` container matcher incorrectly with `void*`

Try to find the correct matcher for `void*` from [here](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet)